# Mysql error "Access denied for user"

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to backup mysql database using php.
I tried the code below:

```
    <?php
   $dbhost = 'my_host';
   $dbuser = 'my_user';
   $dbpass = 'my_pass';
   $db = 'my_dbname';

   $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $db);

   if(! $conn ) {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

   $table_name = "my_table";
   $backup_file  = "/tmp/my_table.sql";
   $sql = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '$backup_file' FROM $table_name";

   mysql_select_db($db);
   $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

   if(! $retval ) {
      die('Could not take data backup: ' . mysql_error());
   }

   echo "Backedup  data successfully\n";

   mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

but I got this error:

"Could not take data backup: Access denied for user 'my_user'@'%' (using password: YES)"

Could you help me, please? Thanks!

Comment: Can you remove the SQL Server tag.  It's a different product.  Anyone posting a SQL Server solution won't be able to help you here.

Comment: does your user have acces rights to this database and from the host you are running your script at? plus: please refrain from mysql_function, since they are deprecated and in PHP7 removed, use mysqli_ or PDO instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'my_host';
$dbuser = 'my_user';
$dbpass = 'my_pass';
$db = 'my_dbname';

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $db);

if(! $conn ) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$table_name = "my_table";
$backup_file  = "/tmp/my_table.sql";
$sql = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '$backup_file' FROM $table_name";

// set current db with connection resource
mysql_select_db(db, $conn);

$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

if(! $retval ) {
  die('Could not take data backup: ' . mysql_error());
}

echo "Backedup  data successfully\n";

mysql_close($conn);
```